# Node.js curl: (55) Send failure: Broken pipe error

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, upload, pipe

I want upload large file. (15 GB) But curl result: broken pipe? What am I doing wrong??

app.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res){

var newFile = fs.createWriteStream('new_file.mkv');
var method = req.method;
var newSize = 0;

if(method == 'PUT'){

  req.pipe(newFile);

  req.on('data', function(chunk){

    newSize += chunk.length;
    console.log(newSize);
  });

}
}).listen(8000, function(){

console.log('Listening..');
});
```

console command:

```
curl --upload-file read.mkv http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Result:

```
curl: (55) Send failure: Broken pipe
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes the Broken Pipe Error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584904/what-causes-the-broken-pipe-error)

Comment: Soultion? I don't understand.

Comment: can you try the command: `curl -iv -F name=filename -F filedata=@read.mkv http://127.0.0.1:8000`. I didn´t test, please ensure that there is no syntax error, or something else

Comment: if you still have problems, with your fileupload you can try this lib: https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable

Comment: Don't run. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I was to facing this above problem in curl command invested a day in debugging this.

Finally resolved by passing extra parameters to curl command (Tested 512MB File transfer).

```
--keepalive-time 600 -iv --limit-rate 500K
```

Try reducing the **limit-rate** and increaing **keepalive-time** at your end.

Hopes this helps the one who reaches there.