# BrokenPipe error occured in send data in socket programing

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I have a client side source code that connects to server over internet.
When I tracing my code it shows me the SIGPIPE error when the compiler run send code. where is my problem?
I changed send method as the comment say and used strcpy.
But I have error again.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */
#include <string>    /*To use string type*/
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <QChar>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <typeinfo>//for print the type typeid(a).name --> int
#include <string>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <signal.h>
//#include <pthread.h> //make thread
using namespace std ;

//________________
#define bufsize 100
int sock;
struct sockaddr_in server;
string str;
char*     message = new char[bufsize];
char*     server_reply = new char[bufsize];
void RECV()
{
        memset(&server_reply,'\0',bufsize);
        int a=recv(sock , server_reply ,bufsize  , 0);
        cout<<a;
        if(server_reply[0]!='\0')
        cout<<server_reply<<endl;

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , IPPROTO_TCP);//0
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("example.com");//
    server.sin_family = AF_UNSPEC;//AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 3490 );


    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected\n");
    puts("Bienvenido al Chatroom, puedes empezar a escribir en la sala!");

    strcpy(message,"Hi");
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    if((send(sock , message , strlen(message)+1 , 0))<0)
    {
        perror("send");
        exit(1);
    }
    RECV();   
    close(sock);
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both `memset` calls, you are passing the address of the pointer rather than the pointer itself.  Because `bufsize` is `100`, these `memset` calls will corrupt other memory.  At that point, any number of bad things can happen.

Below is my version of your code that does not get the `SIGPIPE`. Most notable is that `AF_UNSPEC` has been changed to `AF_INET`.

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define bufsize 100

static int sock;
static char* message      = new char[bufsize];
static char* server_reply = new char[bufsize];

static void RECV(int sock)
{
  recv(sock, server_reply, bufsize, 0);

  printf("%s\n", server_reply);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct sockaddr_in server;

  message      = new char[bufsize];
  server_reply = new char[bufsize];

  sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

  if (sock == -1)
  {
    printf("Could not create socket");
    return 1;
  }

  puts("Socket created");
  server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("93.184.216.34");
  server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server.sin_port = htons( 80 );

  if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
  {
    perror("connect failed. Error");
    return 1;
  }

  puts("Connected\n");
  puts("Bienvenido al Chatroom, puedes empezar a escribir en la sala!");

  strcpy(message,"GET http://example.com/index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n");
  signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);

  if ((send(sock, message, strlen(message)+1, 0))<0)
  {
    perror("send");
    return 1;
  }

  puts("Sent\n");
  RECV(sock);
  close(sock);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I changed the code from memset to " for(int i=0;i<100;i++) message[i]='\0';" but I have the same error

Comment: Why write a loop?  Just remove the `&` from the `memset` call. That is what the answer given is basically stating.  You're calling `memset` incorrectly.

Comment: I removed & but again error. :(

Comment: You don't need `memset()` at all, but this doesn't answer the question. It should have been posted as a comment.

Comment: I removed memset. but I have error again. In (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584904/what-causes-the-broken-pipe-error) they clode socket. but in my code and server we dont use close( socket)

Comment: The third argument to the `socket` call should be `IPPROTO_TCP`. @EJP is right, of course -- I should have posted a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @H.Ghassami - There are problems with your `send` call and its setup: 1. Change `message="Hi"+'\0';` to `strcpy(message, "Hi");`. 2. Change `send(sock, message, sizeof(message), 0);` to `send(sock, message, strlen(message)+1, 0);`.

Comment: @MarkGlenn thanks . I changed the code and use strcpy and send(sock , message , strlen(message)+1 , 0) but when compiler receive the send line again show me BrokenPipe error

Comment: @H.Ghassami - Did you also change the third argument of the `socket` call to `IPPROTO_TCP`?  (See comment above.)

Comment: thanks.Yes I changed sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , IPPROTO_TCP);//0. but again show me the broken pipe error. ( really thanks for reply)

Comment: @H.Ghassami - A few things: 1) In your edited code, I don't see the `IPPROTO_TCP` in the socket. 2) Your `send` should read: `if (send(...) < 0)`. 3) Are you absolutely certain that the `SIGPIPE` occurs on the `send`?  Place a `puts` after the `send` to be sure. 4) Port `216` is reserved for a license server.  Is this what you are connecting to? Very likely sending `Hi` to a license server will cause it to close your connection. 5) Consider ignoring the `SIGPIPE`  -- `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);` -- and handle the error inline. 6) The third argument to `recv` should be `bufsize`, not `20`.

Comment: @H.Ghassami - I take back #6.  In a blocking `recv`, you should specify the number of bytes that you expect your peer to send you.

Comment: @MarkGlenn: really thanks thank to reply.to answer your Qs:1) I forgot to edit code. I just test it in my code .2)I changed that.3)yes. After I changed these, Again after compiler come on send line the brokenpipe error occured.4)I changed the port to 3490,5)I put your code.6) changed 20 to bufsize ( realy realy thanks again) I shamed. but i dont know why broken pipe occured again(edit source code)

Comment: @H.Ghassami - I recreated the problem.  To get past the `SIGPIPE`, change `AF_UNSPEC` to `AF_INET`. Other things that you must change: 1) Change `example.com` to `93.184.216.34` because `inet_addr` only accepts an IP address. 2) Change port `3490` to `80` because you are connecting to an `HTTP` service. 3) You should remove the `memset` because it is unnecessary and will cause corruption the way it is coded (see previous comments). 4) Change `"Hi"` to `"GET http://example.com/index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"` so that the server will send you something to `recv`.

Comment: @MarlGlenn: really thanks to helping me. I changed my server from internet to localhost and also changed #4 and #1(from your comment) ,then problem solved. after that I get that my Ubuntu on VMware dose not access to internet( over bridge network) and I think cause of this I got that error from send method. although , really thanks to help me. thanks