# svn: E175002: MERGE request on svn/xxx failed: 504 Gateway Time-out. Can't write response to output: Broken pipe

Tags: post-commit, broken-pipe, svnsync

**Client ERROR:**

```
svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):

svn: E175002: MERGE request on '/svn/my_repos/trunk/app' failed: 504 Gateway Time-out
```

**Server ERROR LOG:**

```
[Thu Aug 25 09:24:49.466833 2016] [dav:error] [pid 20669] [client 192.168.2.99:31447] Could not MERGE resource "/svn/my_repos/!svn/txn/68582-1h18" into "/svn/my_repos/trunk/app".  [500, #0]

[Thu Aug 25 09:24:49.466882 2016] [dav:error] [pid 20669] [client 192.168.2.99:31447] Error constructing resource list.  [500, #32]

[Thu Aug 25 09:24:49.466884 2016] [dav:error] [pid 20669] [client 192.168.2.99:31447] Can't write response to output: Broken pipe  [500, #32]
```

Answer (score 0):

**in my case ,there error was caused by post-commit svnsync.**

I changed this command:

`/usr/bin/svnsync sync  --non-interactive --username svnsync --password ****** ${svn_mirror_url}`

to run background and redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null

`/usr/bin/svnsync sync  --non-interactive --username svnsync --password ****** ${svn_mirror_url} >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &`

**reference links:**

```
http://subversion.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1065&viewType=browseAll&dsMessageId=685574#messagefocus
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584904/what-causes-the-broken-pipe-error
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60222/why-does-subversion-give-a-broken-pipe-error-when-piped-into-head
```