# Broken Pipe in httpServer in java

Tags: java, httpserver, broken-pipe

I made an httpServer in java in order to send files to a client. The problem is that after I send the file I've been asked for me server keeps getting null commands in buffereader and throws broken Pipe exception. Is there a way to avoid getting null commands??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes the Broken Pipe Error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584904/what-causes-the-broken-pipe-error)

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a 'null command in `BufferedReader`', but there is such a thing as `BufferedReader.readLine()` returning null, which means the peer has closed the connection, and you should do likewise.

Comment: You are rigth. I didn't write it correctly. My problem is that with BufferedReader.readLine() returns null and my programm throws exception. Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Yes, do what I said in my answer.