# WebSocket error occurred: Broken pipe

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

When i start and running rails i got the socket error every page loading.
really i don't know, I asked few members. How to fix this problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV1u2.png)

```
[ActionCable] [user@gmail.com] WebSocket error occurred: Broken pipe
[ActionCable] [user@gmail.com] WebSocket error occurred: Broken pipe
[ActionCable] [user@gmail.com] WebSocket error occurred: Broken pipe
[ActionCable] [user@gmail.com] WebSocket error occurred: Broken pipe
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584904/what-causes-the-broken-pipe-error

Comment: The question doesn't have enough details to enable us to answer it. As to the Broken Pipe error, see the link Mark provided... as a very loose (and maybe inaccurate) guideline, you might think of it as indicating that the socket was closed by the other party.

Comment: i have attached image here