# How to find the reason for crash in xamarin.android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, crash-reports, crash-dumps

I have the below crash log from my console

```
 Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_06
AM write failed: Broken pipe
Error (3675) / DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Error (3675) / DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/k3gxx/k3g:6.0.1/MMB29K/G900HXXU1CQB2:user/release-keys'
Error (3675) / DEBUG: Revision: '10'
Error (3675) / DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
Error (3675) / DEBUG: pid: 2801, tid: 2837, name: Threadpool work  >>> com.linx.candidate <<<
Error (3675) / DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x91ec6120
Error (3675) / DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 0000000d  r2 ae9c9598  r3 9023e930
Error (3675) / DEBUG:     r4 98bd13c8  r5 00000008  r6 9566277c  r7 ae9d5fb0
Error (3675) / DEBUG:     r8 ae6393f0  r9 ae6393f0  sl 96dff784  fp 96dff784
Error (3675) / DEBUG:     ip 95663238  sp 96dfef38  lr 95662ce8  pc 91ec6120  cpsr 200b0010
Error (3675) / DEBUG: 
Error (3675) / DEBUG: backtrace:
Error (3675) / DEBUG:     #00 pc 0000a120  <unknown>
Error (3675) / DEBUG:     #01 pc 00008ce4  <unknown>
Error (3675) / DEBUG: 
Error (3675) / DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_06
Error (3675) / DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
```

Using the above crash,i followed the steps given in

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack.html,

1. Created a txt file of crash
2. Unzipped my apk to give the pash of lib folder
3. Follow the ndk commands for crash anaysis

but my output was

```
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/k3gxx/k3g:6.0.1/MMB29K/G900HXXU1CQB2:user/release-keys'
pid: 2801, tid: 2837, name: Threadpool work  >>> app bundle id <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x91ec6120
Stack frame #00 pc 0000a120  <unknown>
Stack frame #01 pc 00008ce4  <unknown>
:Crash
```

Is there any way to properly de-symbolicate the crash?

Comment: use try catch and check exception stack trace

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584904/what-causes-the-broken-pipe-error