# pda/pheanstalk/src/Socket/StreamFunctions.php fwrite(): send of 219 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Tags: php, sockets, beanstalkd, pheanstalk

pda/pheanstalk/src/Socket/StreamFunctions.php fwrite(): send of 219 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe
How can we solve this problem by reporting this frequently if the quantity is higher

I tried to recreate the reply, but it didn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584904/what-causes-the-broken-pipe-error

Comment: it happens when you try to write data to a closed or disconnected socket.
you can try before sending data with Pheanstalk, check the connection to Beanstalkd and reconnect if needed. Or add a "retry" mechanism